# Facing issue in verifier.sol file

Tags: solidity, zksnark

This is Junaid and I have been working on incorporating ZK SNARKs within a voting application. I am facing some issues regarding the deployment of the contracts.

I am sharing the link for the repo that I have been working on.
https://github.com/Blockchain-E-Voting/EthzkSNARK-Voting/tree/master/contracts

First I am facing the issue in the 'verifier.sol' file for the switch statement. When I tried to resolve it by replacing the switch statement with if/else statement but then the compiler didn't able to identify the 'call' function and threw error 'Call' function not identified. I am using the solc (solidity compiler) version 0.4.23.

Original code:

```
/// @return the sum of two points of G1
function addition(G1Point p1, G1Point p2) internal returns (G1Point r) {
        uint[4] memory input;
        input[0] = p1.X;
        input[1] = p1.Y;
        input[2] = p2.X;
        input[3] = p2.Y;
        bool success;
        assembly
        {
            success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60)
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work 
            switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        }
        require(success);
    }
```

Now what I tried was:

```
/// @return the sum of two points of G1
     function addition(G1Point p1, G1Point p2) internal returns (G1Point r) {
        uint[4] memory input;
        input[0] = p1.X;
        input[1] = p1.Y;
        input[2] = p2.X;
        input[3] = p2.Y;
        bool success;
        assembly {
            success = call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60);
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work     
        //switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        //require(success);
        if (success == 0) {
            invalid();
        }
        else{
             require(success);
    }
   }
}
```

It would be great if anyone would help me in getting this application run properly.

Looking forward to your contribution.

Best Regards,

**The whole code of this file is,**

```
// This file is MIT Licensed.
//
// Copyright 2017 Christian Reitwiessner
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
library Pairing {
    struct G1Point {
        uint X;
        uint Y;
    }
    // Encoding of field elements is: X[0] * z + X[1]
    struct G2Point {
        uint[2] X;
        uint[2] Y;
    }
    /// @return the generator of G1
    function P1() pure internal returns (G1Point) {
        return G1Point(1, 2);
    }
    /// @return the generator of G2
    function P2() pure internal returns (G2Point) {
        return G2Point(
            [11559732032986387107991004021392285783925812861821192530917403151452391805634,
             10857046999023057135944570762232829481370756359578518086990519993285655852781],
            [4082367875863433681332203403145435568316851327593401208105741076214120093531,
             8495653923123431417604973247489272438418190587263600148770280649306958101930]
        );
    }
    /// @return the negation of p, i.e. p.addition(p.negate()) should be zero.
    function negate(G1Point p) internal pure  returns (G1Point) {
        // The prime q in the base field F_q for G1
        uint q = 21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583;
        if (p.X == 0 && p.Y == 0)
            return G1Point(0, 0);
        return G1Point(p.X, q - (p.Y % q));
    }
    /// @return the sum of two points of G1
    function addition(G1Point p1, G1Point p2) internal returns (G1Point r) {
        uint[4] memory input;
        input[0] = p1.X;
        input[1] = p1.Y;
        input[2] = p2.X;
        input[3] = p2.Y;
        bool success;
            success = call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60);
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work     
        //switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        //require(success);
    //}
    if iszero(success) {
    revert(0, 0)
}
    /// @return the product of a point on G1 and a scalar, i.e.
    /// p == p.scalar_mul(1) and p.addition(p) == p.scalar_mul(2) for all points p.
    function scalar_mul(G1Point p, uint s) internal returns (G1Point r) {
        uint[3] memory input;
        input[0] = p.X;
        input[1] = p.Y;
        input[2] = s;
        bool success;
        assembly 
        {
            success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 7, 0, input, 0x80, r, 0x60)
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
            switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        }
        require (success);
    }
    /// @return the result of computing the pairing check
    /// e(p1[0], p2[0]) *  .... * e(p1[n], p2[n]) == 1
    /// For example pairing([P1(), P1().negate()], [P2(), P2()]) should
    /// return true.
    function pairing(G1Point[] p1, G2Point[] p2) internal returns (bool) {
        require(p1.length == p2.length);
        uint elements = p1.length;
        uint inputSize = elements * 6;
        uint[] memory input = new uint[](inputSize);
        for (uint i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            input[i * 6 + 0] = p1[i].X;
            input[i * 6 + 1] = p1[i].Y;
            input[i * 6 + 2] = p2[i].X[0];
            input[i * 6 + 3] = p2[i].X[1];
            input[i * 6 + 4] = p2[i].Y[0];
            input[i * 6 + 5] = p2[i].Y[1];
        }
        uint[1] memory out;
        bool success;
        assembly {
            success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 8, 0, add(input, 0x20), mul(inputSize, 0x20), out, 0x20)
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
            switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        }
        require(success);
        return out[0] != 0;
    }
    /// Convenience method for a pairing check for two pairs.
    function pairingProd2(G1Point a1, G2Point a2, G1Point b1, G2Point b2) internal returns (bool) {
        G1Point[] memory p1 = new G1Point[](2);
        G2Point[] memory p2 = new G2Point[](2);
        p1[0] = a1;
        p1[1] = b1;
        p2[0] = a2;
        p2[1] = b2;
        return pairing(p1, p2);
    }
    /// Convenience method for a pairing check for three pairs.
    function pairingProd3(
            G1Point a1, G2Point a2,
            G1Point b1, G2Point b2,
            G1Point c1, G2Point c2
    ) internal returns (bool) {
        G1Point[] memory p1 = new G1Point[](3);
        G2Point[] memory p2 = new G2Point[](3);
        p1[0] = a1;
        p1[1] = b1;
        p1[2] = c1;
        p2[0] = a2;
        p2[1] = b2;
        p2[2] = c2;
        return pairing(p1, p2);
    }
    /// Convenience method for a pairing check for four pairs.
    function pairingProd4(
            G1Point a1, G2Point a2,
            G1Point b1, G2Point b2,
            G1Point c1, G2Point c2,
            G1Point d1, G2Point d2
    ) internal returns (bool) {
        G1Point[] memory p1 = new G1Point[](4);
        G2Point[] memory p2 = new G2Point[](4);
        p1[0] = a1;
        p1[1] = b1;
        p1[2] = c1;
        p1[3] = d1;
        p2[0] = a2;
        p2[1] = b2;
        p2[2] = c2;
        p2[3] = d2;
        return pairing(p1, p2);
    }
}
contract Verifier {
    using Pairing for *;
    struct VerifyingKey {
        Pairing.G2Point A;
        Pairing.G1Point B;
        Pairing.G2Point C;
        Pairing.G2Point gamma;
        Pairing.G1Point gammaBeta1;
        Pairing.G2Point gammaBeta2;
        Pairing.G2Point Z;
        Pairing.G1Point[] IC;
    }
    struct Proof {
        Pairing.G1Point A;
        Pairing.G1Point A_p;
        Pairing.G2Point B;
        Pairing.G1Point B_p;
        Pairing.G1Point C;
        Pairing.G1Point C_p;
        Pairing.G1Point K;
        Pairing.G1Point H;
    }
    function verifyingKey() pure internal returns (VerifyingKey vk) {
        vk.A = Pairing.G2Point([0x33de61db4f5934f8646980bdbb09ba19ff68983c38d0967196b01b972a50fb5, 0x167096f00a6c7a01607c19b1351cd9b1c50bcfaec5fed77ad98e7fe876511374], [0x2751b1f30775dd81454dee862b4d02e91ad15756d6224756aedbe58ca06c216, 0x26a09b5bbd5cdb912b8f09d707f1741a9ac48d6e0f73e862236f051b73d53b55]);
        vk.B = Pairing.G1Point(0x18f8de99ee586e675b3f9fea80f25f3283d9c03a13b26107a6d883aee82b5c73, 0x21f33c90cd3fb9d1bc8ea131bfc7b7850846d5fffb70ce66a2dceb7799b8d99a);
        vk.C = Pairing.G2Point([0x2f5e4b788b4a2c2174e8c4d97bbae932484eb5535aec9fe311bf4f9387aa1d01, 0x2cdf2769a28bc1d11fc1de2372925cfefab1e560b08cc719cff37d99b7e87091], [0x18fbcdeaae46d19281d396f5f641e3b67af55b3f77cd2ec671606587ee1a6b42, 0x239ded808e68ea3781235d66a136c938c968bca62f8aa002379db00225f1c5ca]);
        vk.gamma = Pairing.G2Point([0x615bf5be61b937ea94d053bc81eebba8ab2effe55783f81c39d1c95ab7a957e, 0x10c8ed52c3f5c843c968d5c09acde4840734b4c9d723d0cb6ea0a7e3a5d85dca], [0x640498f9bc8bb0e2336c502aad129c0a1ee9ba61e8f44ad39b1f13f36ce9076, 0x2f698085427044680920d514f67e26ff984824f1464a27fee5b83e5d27513c46]);
        vk.gammaBeta1 = Pairing.G1Point(0x2a99bc15b1edfa1c86a9fd7ed333d5cb0d35282b0e907d5baa644ce6d2049851, 0x1e289523f69aacdb76ba5747367454b7594b133baf97d8eb6d8780d74e29b9ec);
        vk.gammaBeta2 = Pairing.G2Point([0x21041f7250d4dc2b96e166d86130b6f3466d59b75658c1aabe8a208275c5fe04, 0x2e11b8c7f4a97d9c2f8fccef3760b5ccf3a11ed9f9c38159a450534aa8f35195], [0x29e0bf2a6723a9ba6ca0f687338d7eb9450e0a4d6cceb91e54347296b18a26da, 0x23fc872cff5f984f77e78f68039a263be7b40768518c92ae4dd81ff66b06fa46]);
        vk.Z = Pairing.G2Point([0x235d9e4193d28bebc47c55d58ce05b8d7f2cb26f09b06b8c85c9dd70139dba0e, 0xd6395535f6adbc98bcfc87ae2d56950e266f445de3c1e9287b022d63585ea87], [0x124d45c1d43d9406886ddfa86c5be4d0a2840ce061fdfa1910c58d715b50fbaa, 0x40395fdc52a1ca64779871db11b78e98f97ee85df07c7ebee711e3c7ca9f7d3]);
        vk.IC = new Pairing.G1Point[](2);
        vk.IC[0] = Pairing.G1Point(0x134b88b827ad466340562ce6ae375307bfecd1fbed4dd78a3bba7742c5eb45f1, 0x18fa4f8997558930b456921ebecefbeadcd875b0298a27c9ba69d9eea45e8eea);
        vk.IC[1] = Pairing.G1Point(0x1d694a79a0570423a77d5415ffbf690443a9877b396a88286d54146550c3c178, 0xc4e475824a8dcf1ddc0eb5b2bcacf60401123a68892ea8dae0d69956e84c214);
    }
    function verify(uint[] input, Proof proof) internal returns (uint) {
        VerifyingKey memory vk = verifyingKey();
        require(input.length + 1 == vk.IC.length);
        // Compute the linear combination vk_x
        Pairing.G1Point memory vk_x = Pairing.G1Point(0, 0);
        for (uint i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            vk_x = Pairing.addition(vk_x, Pairing.scalar_mul(vk.IC[i + 1], input[i]));
        vk_x = Pairing.addition(vk_x, vk.IC[0]);
        if (!Pairing.pairingProd2(proof.A, vk.A, Pairing.negate(proof.A_p), Pairing.P2())) return 1;
        if (!Pairing.pairingProd2(vk.B, proof.B, Pairing.negate(proof.B_p), Pairing.P2())) return 2;
        if (!Pairing.pairingProd2(proof.C, vk.C, Pairing.negate(proof.C_p), Pairing.P2())) return 3;
        if (!Pairing.pairingProd3(
            proof.K, vk.gamma,
            Pairing.negate(Pairing.addition(vk_x, Pairing.addition(proof.A, proof.C))), vk.gammaBeta2,
            Pairing.negate(vk.gammaBeta1), proof.B
        )) return 4;
        if (!Pairing.pairingProd3(
                Pairing.addition(vk_x, proof.A), proof.B,
                Pairing.negate(proof.H), vk.Z,
                Pairing.negate(proof.C), Pairing.P2()
        )) return 5;
        return 0;
    }
    event Verified(string s);
    function verifyTx(
            uint[2] a,
            uint[2] a_p,
            uint[2][2] b,
            uint[2] b_p,
            uint[2] c,
            uint[2] c_p,
            uint[2] h,
            uint[2] k,
            uint[1] input
        ) public returns (bool r) {
        Proof memory proof;
        proof.A = Pairing.G1Point(a[0], a[1]);
        proof.A_p = Pairing.G1Point(a_p[0], a_p[1]);
        proof.B = Pairing.G2Point([b[0][0], b[0][1]], [b[1][0], b[1][1]]);
        proof.B_p = Pairing.G1Point(b_p[0], b_p[1]);
        proof.C = Pairing.G1Point(c[0], c[1]);
        proof.C_p = Pairing.G1Point(c_p[0], c_p[1]);
        proof.H = Pairing.G1Point(h[0], h[1]);
        proof.K = Pairing.G1Point(k[0], k[1]);
        uint[] memory inputValues = new uint[](input.length);
        for(uint i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            inputValues[i] = input[i];
        }
        if (verify(inputValues, proof) == 0) {
            emit Verified("Transaction successfully verified.");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried to resolve it by replacing the `switch` statement with `if`/`else` statement": 1. Please share the relevant piece of code (don't make us jump to your link and search for it). 2. Please show how you've changed it (how exactly are we supposed to determine the reason for your compilation issue otherwise???).

Comment: function addition(G1Point p1, G1Point p2) internal returns (G1Point r) {
        uint[4] memory input;
        input[0] = p1.X;
        input[1] = p1.Y;
        input[2] = p2.X;
        input[3] = p2.Y;
        bool success;
         {
            success = call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60);
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work 
            if (success == 0){
                invalid();
            }
            else{
                require(success);
            }
    }

Comment: Post it properly formatted as part of your question please.

Comment: this is what I tried to resolve the issue. The original code was,

bool success;
            success = call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60);
switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        require(success);
}

Comment: **Properly formatted as part of your question** (not in the comment section)!

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: What is `G1Point`?

Comment: This cannot be the original code (I'm referring to your properly formatted code snippet, not to that huge code dump that you've added at the end of your question)!!! The bottom part in function `addition` should be encapsulated with `assembly { ... }`. Please read the original code carefully and try to be a little more meticulous in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can simply change `if (success == 0)` to `if iszero(success)`.

However, you may also try changing this:

```
if (success == 0) {
    invalid();
}
else {
    require(success);
}
```

To this:

```
if iszero(success) {
    revert(0, 0) // assuming that there are 2 fields in the `G1Point` structure
}
```

Comment: showing an error "expected token Lparen got identifier"

Comment: @user58235: On which line of code?

Comment: On iszero function.
this line exactly:  if iszero(success) {

Comment: @user58235: Are you kidding me??? Where is the `assembly` from the original code? Why did you remove it in your question???

Comment: So are you trying to say that I should go like this?

 bool success;
        assembly {
            success = call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60);
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work     
        //switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        //require(success);
        if iszero(success) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

Comment: So this is what you are trying to say?

 bool success;
        assembly {
            success = call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60);
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work     
        //switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        //require(success);
        if iszero(success) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

Comment: @user58235: Please fix the `Original code` part in your question, according to what the original code really is. Then, I will be able to address your question here.

Comment: Done it. Now please take a look into it.

Comment: @user58235: I don't get it. Now you've fixed not only the original code, but also your attempted code, which you have changed to the answer that I've given you. You cannot keep changing the **actual part** of your question like this, because it turns the given answers obsolete!!! Also, now that you've changed it, there's a missing `}` to close the `assembly` block.

Comment: Ok. Now please guide according to the code I have last updated. Still the error is there after adding the '}'.

Comment: @user58235: No I won't. Please fix it to how it was prior to my answer. You can leave the `assembly` part, but the `if iszero(success)` part is from my answer, which therefore turns obsolete is respect with your question. After you do that, please note exactly what the error is.

Comment: Please check now. I have reverted all changes I made.

Comment: So... have you tried my suggested changes now?

Comment: Yes I did but the error was still there