# zkSTARK verifier in Solidity

Tags: solidity, zksnark

There are zkSNARK verifier in Solidity such as [this](https://gist.github.com/chriseth/f9be9d9391efc5beb9704255a8e2989d) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80116/facing-issue-in-verifier-sol-file). Is there such Solidity verifier for zkSTARK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing identical  The zkSnark ones are made by the IDEN folks with their snarkjs library:  https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs

The only thing I know of is this:  https://github.com/starkware-libs/starkex-contracts/blob/master/evm-verifier/solidity/contracts/StarkVerifier.sol. by the starkware folks.  It's a solidity file, but verifies Cairo programs, so could be useful.

Comment: Do u know the gas cost of verifying a STARK proof?

Comment: don't have a txn, but this article says ~5M gas:  https://ethresear.ch/t/checkpoints-for-faster-finality-in-starknet/9633

Comment: This one claims ~2.5M https://github.com/matter-labs/awesome-zero-knowledge-proofs#comparison-of-the-most-popular-zkp-systems